# How do I shorten this switch case?

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I'm new to swift, can someone let me know if I can improve this switch statement? Or a new approach?

```
switch (a, b) {
case (c, bb),
     (cc, bb),
     (ccc, bb):
   // do something like print (1)
case (z, bb),
     (zz, bb),
     (zzz, bb):
   // do something like print (2)
case (x, bc):
   // do something like print (3)
}
```

Is it possible to do the following? Or something similar?

```
case ((c OR cc OR ccc), bb):
// do something? 
case ((z OR zz OR zzz), bb):
// do something?
```

How can I shorten this switch case?

Comment: have a look at `where`-clauses: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID134

Comment: To get a proper answer, you'll need to describe exactly what `c`, `cc`, `ccc`, etc. are, and what the relationships betwen them are

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few options.

If c, cc, ccc and z, zz, zzz are contiguous ranges of values, there are a couple of ways to use the range operator:

```
switch (a, b) {
case (c...ccc, bb):
    print("matched \(a), bb")
case (let x, bb) where z...zzz ~= x:
    print("matched \(x), bb")
}
```

If testing with ranges won't work, some basic `where` expressions will work, though I don't think this looks very nice when there are more than two values to test:

```
switch (a, b) {
case (let x, bb) where x == c || x == cc || x == ccc:
    print("matched \(x), bb")
case (_, bb) where a == z || a == zz || a == zzz:
    print("matched \(a), bb")
}
```

Here's an example using an array and the `contains` function, which looks a little better when you have a lot of values to test:

```
switch (a, b) {
case (let x, bb) where [c, cc, ccc].contains(x):
    print("matched \(x), bb")
case (_, bb) where [z, zz, zzz].contains(a):
    print("matched \(a), bb")
}
```

I can't think of a more native Swift syntax that's similar to your `((c OR cc OR ccc), bb)` idea for testing multiple cases in a mure succinct way.

Stepping back a bit, in your specific scenario, there could be value in moving some of this logic (such as the c/cc/ccc tests) into separate functions or vars. For example:

```
switch (a, b) {
case (_, bb) where a.isOneOfTheCValues:
case (_, bb) where a.isOneOfTheZValues:
case (x, bc):
}
```